# Statistical Learning Theory - Loss Function

Tags: statistical-learning, vc-dimension

I am reading Vapnik's "Statistical Learning Theory" and I am confused about his use of Q(z,alpha). On page 23 he explains that Q is the loss function which takes as argument a function g, the function used by the learning algorithm to generate predictions:

Q(z,alpha) = L(z,g(z,alpha))

However, later in the book (p.147), when defining the concept of VC dimension he uses Q(z,alpha) as if it was g(z,alpha). He talks about a set of indicator functions Q(z,alpha) shattering sets of points and later talks about the capacity of Q. Usually people refer to VC dimension as a property of the function implemented by the leaning algorithm g not as a property of the loss function Q. What am I missing?

Comment: If the Loss function is a function of g(z,alpha) and Q is a function of the loss function, then Q yet is a function of g(z,alpha), right? Therefore it still is a property of the learning algorithms function, right?

Comment: Q is not a function of the loss function, Q is the loss function, but that isn't really important. And no, the loss function is not really part of the function learned by the learning algo. Once training is done, there is no more loss function involved - just g. But may that as it be, what I find confusing is that the loss function should not be what determines the VC dimension but the function g which generates the predictions. It doesn't seem to make sense to say a loss function shatters a set. I can only see that this makes sense for g.

Comment: If we take an indicator model and associate it with a 0-1 loss function, it seems relatively straightforward to infer that the two will have the same VC dimension, although I completely agree the manner of exposition is less than helpful.

I have not seen enough examples of how Vapnik presents real-valued functions. However, in the mixture of normal distributions he presents on page 128, he states the "model" in terms of the probability density function $p$, and this links monotonically to his proposed loss function, $\ln{p}$. Here the classifier logic seems to extend intuitively.